# Difference between were here / checkin numbers

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I access:

https://www.facebook.com/clubambassadeur

I get a specific number for "were here"

But if I access:

http://graph.facebook.com/clubambassadeur

I get a different number listed under checkins.

Why are these two numbers different? I was assuming they represent the same thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first link's "were here" equals check-ins + friends tagged in the check-ins that a place has got.

Your second link shows only check-ins, which is a sub-set of "were here" and doesn't include tagged people.

Comment: Thank you. How did you know this? Is there a reference page that covers this? For future reference.

Comment: To my knowledge it's not part of the public API. I know it from the media coverage when it was launched. I was building a Facebook app then and tried to integrate the "were here" for places but couldn't find it in the API.

Answer (score 3):

Although many people online agree with Gunnar, I don't think his is the correct answer.

Please compare these two:

- http://graph.facebook.com/amshopping (342 checkins)
- https://www.facebook.com/amshopping (14,125 people were here)

It seems highly unlikely that an average checkin has 41 people tagged.

Here's what I think:

- "checkins" == total number of actual checkins (not people), probably with a cell phone
- "were here" == I don't know. I thought it was total number of people that have mentioned the @page in a facebook post, but I couldn't prove this when I tested it.
- "people who have checked in"* == total number of unique people who have checked in at any time

. * Only available to administrators of a place page. See insights -> checkins.

Comment: Those numbers (a few years later) appear to be identical now.

Comment: they may look identical for a percentage of pages but this is not true for all even today. see https://www.facebook.com/courtyard/

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is some years old but nevertheless I stumbled upon it and didn't found a proper explanation. So there is a documentation now:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/page tells:

**checkins:**

> Number of checkins at a place represented by a Page.

**were_here_count**

> The number of visits to this Page's location. [...]

So what I do understand: A page can have a location. That location can have multiple pages (which makes sense, imagine a shopping mall: same address, multiple shops=>pages).
The checkins represent the value of all visitors of that page(= shop), whereas were_here_count stands for all visits from all locations which do have the exact coordinates.
Sadly I couldn't find an example for proving that.

Comment: Version 2.2 of the API cleares some other thing up: checkins are Core API fields, were_here_count can be disabled by site owners: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page. At least that is new to me :)

Comment: this explanation looks logical to me. Note how they have explicitly said "Page's location" vs "place represented by a Page"

Answer (score 0):

I guess "were here" also sums the tagged pictures. For example someone travels to France and uploads an album of 200 pictures and tags the album as being in France.

Answer (score 0):

Through experimentation I can confirm that the *were here* count gets increased whenever somebody mentions a place in a post. The post get's suffixed with "- at X". But apparently if you post the same location twice in a row it won't count.